# What is causing letters to be repeated in this text input in Google Chrome for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I am developing a webapp with a text input that provides suggestions via a dynamic datalist. In mobile Chrome for Android, I intermittently but frequently have the first 3 or 4 letters typed into the input repeated. It appears that this behavior manifests itself mostly when I type into the input quickly after the page loads.

Here is a [youtube video of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAwfkBR9h_g) (It will probably help you see the keystrokes if you watch it in slow-mo...0.5x or 0.25x).

The datalist options are populated as such: `oninput` calls a javascript function sending the `input`'s value via ajax to a php script. This php script `SELECT`s the results from a MySql db that match the `input` value. The results are `echo`ed back to the original page in `<option>` tags. I have not included any functionality that changes the `input`'s value based on the query. The only items affected are the `<option>`s in the `<datalist>`.

I haven't noticed this behavior in other text inputs on my site, and the major thing that makes this `input` different is the ajax call. I also have not been able to replicate this behavior on desktop even when emulating mobile through DevTools. I do sometimes have extremely quirky keyboard behavior on my Android phone when using some native apps like Facebook Messenger for instance, but my gut feeling is this example is not related. I have used both LG Keyboard and Google's Gboard, and the problem is occurring with both.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form id="regform" method="post" action="submit.php">
        <legend>Input?</legend>
        <input type="text" required="true" id="inp" name="inp" placeholder="input" oninput="sendquery();" list="options" autofocus />
        <datalist id="options">
        </datalist><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    function sendquery() {
        var sendstr = $('#inp').val();
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                $('#options').html(this.responseText);                          
            }
        };  
        xhttp.open("GET", "getoptions.php?str="+sendstr, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

I don't think my CSS or PHP is causing the problem, so I'm omitting it for now.

Obviously, the desired behavior is simply for each key press to result in that character being entered into the input once. Also, for the datalist to provide a narrowing list of suggestions. If I type somewhat slower than I prefer, this is what occurs (or at least I have not noticed it when typing slowly).

What could be causing this?

Comment: I suggest you to not make XHR calls at input event listener or at least debounce the callback to prevent an overload of request. Maybe this is what is causing the problem. Check how to debounce the function here https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086

Comment: @MaxiDiaz this is a good suggestion regardless, but it did not solve my problem when I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a bug in Chrome for Android.
Or something else very fishy going on (like a very clumsy keylogger?).

The workaround which worked for me is to remember the input value on the keyup event and overwrite the input field with this stored value on the next keydown event.

I experienced the same issue when I added some event-handlers to format the input.

It seems that the event handlers are a contributor, but I did not find a reliable setup how to create any different event-handler which causes this issue. Also I noticed not all devices experiencing the issue.

It requires further investigation.